# Dynamic Dataweave script to create salesforce record in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, dataweave

I have a Salesforce object, which has a growing set of fields. I know that each field in the csv file will map into this object, and each column name in the csv will match the field-name in Salesforce. Can I write a DW that can be loosely coupled to the schema, something like;

```
records map(record) -> {

<for each label, get the value>
$.label : $.value
</>

} as Object {class: "CustomObject__c"}
```

Is such a thing conceptually possible in DW? Excuse the co-opted xml delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you have a CSV that contains the data to be used to create a specific object that is going to be used in a Salesforce operation later. If the CSV fields matches the object key-values 1:1 then probably you don't need to do anything. DataWeave will read each record in the CSV and create an object automatically.

Example:

Input CSV

```csv
A,B,C
1,2,3
```

DataWeave script

```js
output application/java
---
payload
```

Output

```
[{A=1, B=2, C=3}]
```

If you are using the Salesforce connector it is not really expecting a Java class `CustomObject__c` or whatever but a plain DataWeave object that could be implemented internally with Java maps and/or lists.

If instead you need to have an actual key called `CustomObject__c` in your object you could map it in the script.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map {
    CustomObject__c: ($)
}
```

Output

```
[{CustomObject__c={A=1, B=2, C=3}}]
```

Comment: Yeah, wow. that's pretty close. Just by telling DW what output format I want it just does what I want.

"output application/java".

In the Apex scenario, I'd love it if I could do something like

"output application/apex/Contact".

And it would output all the records, as well as add "as Object {class : Contact}" to the end, as per this article. 

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_DataWeaveInApex_DevPreview.htm&release=240&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Hey so maybe this suits your needs.  Would be handy to have an example of your csv but here it goes.  Simple example of zipping the 2 arrays together.

**.csv payload**

```
label,value
cb,52131
ad,55
ca,33355
bd,51
cc,13
cb,53611
bb,26513
```

**Dataweave**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var labels  =  payload map $."label"
var values =  payload map $."value"
---
{
    "Zipped" : zip(labels, values)
}
```

**Output Paylaod**

```
    {
  "Zipped": [
    [
      "cb",
      "52131"
    ],
    [
      "ad",
      "55"
    ],
    [
      "ca",
      "33355"
    ],
    [
      "bd",
      "51"
    ],
    [
      "cc",
      "13"
    ],
    [
      "cb",
      "53611"
    ],
    [
      "bb",
      "26513"
    ]
  ]
}
```